# Does deep linking / universal link work from an webview?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview

I created an iOS application, which supports universal links.
It works when I click on a link from safari. But in my app I also have a webview that contains universal links to the app itself. But on click, it stays in the webview and doesn't re-open the app in the right place instead.
What is the default behavior?
How can I change this?

Is it the same in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Universal links are an iOS specific technology.  Android has a similar technology called [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).  For universal links I would recommend that you look into [CFBundleURLSchemes](http://blog.learningtree.com/en/url-schemes-on-ios/) and their interaction with universal links.